# CakePHP: creating my own functions

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an Article controller & model. I want to have a function that adds one to an integer when a link is clicked. So I have say a "i like" button (link) it takes me to Articles/thumbsup it will then take the thumbsup field of that article and increment it by one, then save the article, and redirect to the view.

I'm not sure how to modify records in this way. I need to load the article, modify the data and then save it.

My hope is that this be handled by javascript so noone will see the url change.

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with an AjaxRequest.

models/article.php:

```
function thumbsup($id = null)
  {
  $conditions = array('Article.id' => $id);
  $this->updateAll(
    array('Article.thumbsup' => 'Article.thumbsup + 1'),
    $conditions
    );
  $article = $this->find(
    'first',
    array('conditions' => $conditions, 'fields' => array('Article.thumbsup'))
    );
  return $article['Article']['thumbsup'];
  }
```

controllers/articles_controller.php:

```
function thumbsup($id = null)
  {
  $this->set('count', $this->Article->thumbsup($id));
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
  }
```

views/articles/thumbsup.ctp:

```
<?php echo $count; ?>
```

webroot/js/thumbsup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $('.iLikeSomething').click(function()
    {
    $.post('http://yoursite.com/articles/incrementThumbsup/'+this.id, function(data)
      {
      $('#iLikeSomethingCount').html(data);
      });
    });
  });
```

Html sample for clicking:

```
<span class="iLikeSomething" id="insertYourArticleIdHere" style="cursor: pointer;">iLike</span>
<div id="iLikeSomethingCount">0</div>
```

Comment: This will create a race condition and lead to inaccurate counts. Use DB to increment.

Comment: Well, that would be a better way indeed. I guess the only way to do that via CakePHP is to use the custom query function, anyone wanna correct me?

Comment: As it turns out - you can add conditions to the UpdateAll() function, I didn't know that. Edited the answer with proper code. Also there is something like http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ketan/2008/05/13/increment-behavior, might want to check it out. Or at least create a function in model, to keep provided code away from the controller.

Comment: thanks for replying! I'm getting a bit confused though, I'm not sure what $count is used for, I'm just getting a undefined variable error.This will also be the first time I'm doing this sort of jQuery call. I have added the jQuery library to js/ and called it in the page. I have added a link with the id 'iLikeSomething'. I've added the javascript to my view but nothing is happening when I like the link

Comment: As I said before - I wrote it in a hurry, forgot about few things. I edited the answer, actually checking the use on my app, it works now.

Comment: Thanks so much PawelMysior! Will try it out!

Comment: Everything apart from the ajax works fine! I don't think I am calling or using the js properly. I've added this to my default layout <?php echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.4.3.min');?>
<?php echo $javascript->link('thumbsup');?> and I have the Javascript helper set in the controller

Comment: Did you try adding alerts? Add: `alert('something');` before $.post in thumbsup.js and see if it gets there.

Comment: no it doesn't fire off an alert :( will have to look into why js isn;t working, thanks for you're help will report back with the issue!